# Show line number on error

Tags: debugging, error-handling, line-numbers, edebug

Say that emacs throws some error that I don't understand. Or maybe the error says "Symbol's value as variable is void: modes", but there are many occurrences of the symbol `modes` in my code, so I need some context. Can Emacs be configured to mention the line number of the lisp code so I can know what code is causing the error?

I have tried doing `(setq stack-trace-on-error '(buffer-read-only))` and ran the perpetrating code in an effort to get a stack trace. No stack trace either.

I have also tried calling `edebug-defun` on my function and stepping through it. It is not until I step out of the function that the error is thrown.

(I am really not as interested in the cause of the particular error I am facing currently as I am in developing general debugging skills for elisp. Please advise on how I can gleam a line number, or a sexp, or a stack trace from an error.)

Comment: Did you already try non-`nil` `debug-on-error`? Doesn't that help?

Comment: Nope. That doesn't seem to do anything. (After I set it to `t` and then proceed to eval an error-throwing function.)

Comment: Probably what happens is that some other code catches the error and just prints the error message. Also check that `debug-ignored-errors` doesn't list any errors. If you set `debug-on-signal` to non-`nil`, and it was the case the other code handled the error, you will be able to get the error before the other code did.

Comment: I am currently in a similar situation and was reading this question. I am wondering about stack-trace-on-error. This variable is not documented in Emacs 25.1.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Emacs provides a good amount of debugging facilities including `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit`, debug on signal (which can be used by sending `USR2` to Emacs from outside), `debug-on-entry` (of a function), `debug-on-message` (when seeing a specific regexp match of a message) and finally, `debug` itself as alternative to instrumenting a function with `C-u C-M-x`.

Both `debug` and `edebug` offer enough functionality to inspect the *state* of Emacs when evaluating the code that you're interested in, hit `e` and enter an expression.

However, while `edebug` jumps to the place in the instrumented function and therefore gives you a clue where to look (which is kind of silly since you already know what exactly you've instrumented), `debug` doesn't do this at all.  I've pulled off a smaller hack after discovering that whenever `debug` evaluates a buffer, it emits the value of point associated with the error; in other words using this information on the buffer can give you a line number in the backtrace!

```
(with-eval-after-load 'debug
  (defun debugger-setup-buffer (debugger-args)
    "Initialize the `*Backtrace*' buffer for entry to the debugger.
That buffer should be current already."
    (setq buffer-read-only nil)
    (erase-buffer)
    (set-buffer-multibyte t)        ;Why was it nil ?  -stef
    (setq buffer-undo-list t)
    (let ((standard-output (current-buffer))
          (print-escape-newlines t)
          (print-level 8)
          (print-length 50))
      (backtrace))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (delete-region (point)
                   (progn
                     (search-forward "\n  debug(")
                     (forward-line (if (eq (car debugger-args) 'debug)
                                       2    ; Remove implement-debug-on-entry frame.
                                     1))
                     (point)))
    (insert "Debugger entered")
    ;; lambda is for debug-on-call when a function call is next.
    ;; debug is for debug-on-entry function called.
    (pcase (car debugger-args)
      ((or `lambda `debug)
       (insert "--entering a function:\n"))
      ;; Exiting a function.
      (`exit
       (insert "--returning value: ")
       (setq debugger-value (nth 1 debugger-args))
       (prin1 debugger-value (current-buffer))
       (insert ?\n)
       (delete-char 1)
       (insert ? )
       (beginning-of-line))
      ;; Debugger entered for an error.
      (`error
       (insert "--Lisp error: ")
       (prin1 (nth 1 debugger-args) (current-buffer))
       (insert ?\n))
      ;; debug-on-call, when the next thing is an eval.
      (`t
       (insert "--beginning evaluation of function call form:\n"))
      ;; User calls debug directly.
      (_
       (insert ": ")
       (prin1 (if (eq (car debugger-args) 'nil)
                  (cdr debugger-args) debugger-args)
              (current-buffer))
       (insert ?\n)))
    ;; After any frame that uses eval-buffer,
    ;; insert a line that states the buffer position it's reading at.
    (save-excursion
      (let ((tem eval-buffer-list))
        (while (and tem
                    (re-search-forward "^  eval-\\(buffer\\|region\\)(" nil t))
          (beginning-of-line)
          (insert (format "Error at line %d in %s: "
                          (with-current-buffer (car tem)
                            (line-number-at-pos (point)))
                          (with-current-buffer (car tem)
                            (buffer-name))))
          (pop tem))))
    (debugger-make-xrefs)))
```

With this the original question in the title should be answered.  As for your problem with getting a backtrace in the first place, I'm out of useful ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still don't understand how to get the line number. `M-x debug` ...? Then what do I press?

Comment: With this code you'll see a line number in backtraces made by `debug`, you can check by visiting a faulty elisp file, doing `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and `M-x eval-buffer`, then a backtrace with a line number at the problematic position should pop up.

Comment: Will this work if you don't use `eval-buffer`? For example, if you just press a keyboard shortcut that runs a private command that fails and opens the debugger in the `*Backtrace*` buffer..

Comment: No, it won't.  You get the function value of the symbol (which can either be a list or something byte-compiled) and that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe because it's 2018 now, but in my case,
I only had to turn on debugging like wasamasa suggested:
     M-x toggle-debug-on-error

After this, M-x eval-buffer on my faulty Elisp file
gave context by providing the position of the error,
like this:

  `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-read-syntax ")")
    eval-buffer()  ; Reading at buffer position 523
  [....]`

M-x goto-char jumps to the error position:

   `M-x goto-char 523`

Comment: Nice find! It appears this has been added in 2017, back when they reworked that function to work on a list of backtrace items.

Comment: Additionally, it seems a button to jump to the location has been added.

Comment: Worked for locating an issue with a function that was added to `kill-emacs-hook`. The trace link didn't work as the function call is wrapped with a lambda function (is that the right way to say that?), but the combination of the actual error (void variable) and the function name gave me all I needed to know.  Also in emacs 28.1, it's a menu item in `MenuBar->Options->Enter Debugger on Error`

Answer (score 1):

I've extended wasamasa's answer to include additional information:

```
(save-excursion
  (let ((tem eval-buffer-list))
    (while (and tem
                (re-search-forward "^  eval-\\(buffer\\|region\\)(" nil t))
      (beginning-of-line)
      (insert (apply 'format "Error at line %d, column %d (point %d) in %s\n"
                     (with-current-buffer (car tem)
                       (list (line-number-at-pos (point))
                             (current-column)
                             (point)
                             (buffer-name)))))
      (pop tem))))
```