# What is this square in the middle of the emacs' GUI?

Tags: gui-emacs, bell

I wonder how could I disable this annoying square which seems like it's zooming in the text under the emacs' cursor.

How can I get rid of it? And what is this exactly?

I am on emacs 24.5 (homebrew installed) and MacOS X El Capitán.

[image]

Comment: This issue is most definitely caused by something in your init file. The standard recommendation is to [bisect it](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13997/2355). (You are unlikely to get a more helpful answer unless you provide more information about your setup.) You can try [The Bug Hunter by @Malabarba](http://endlessparentheses.com/debug-your-emacs-init-file-with-the-bug-hunter.html), though.

Comment: Well, I was wrong (wouldn't be the first time). Sorry about that. Looks like [this](http://stuff-things.net/2015/10/05/emacs-visible-bell-work-around-on-os-x-el-capitan/) is the same issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the cause of the problem is `visible-bell`. Just put the following to your .emacs file:

```
(setq ring-bell-function 'ignore)
```

to get rid of both audible and visible bell

Answer (score 5):

As noted in scaevola's answer, the problem is `visible-bell`. Completely turning off both audible and visible bell may seem a bit drastic, though. Here's a homebrew version of visible bell that just flashes the mode-line – but excluding some cases where the user deliberately caused the condition triggering the bell:

```
(setq ring-bell-function
  (lambda ()
    (unless (memq this-command
          '(isearch-abort abort-recursive-edit
                  exit-minibuffer keyboard-quit))
      (invert-face 'mode-line)
      (run-with-timer 0.1 nil 'invert-face 'mode-line))))
```

Adjust the delay 0.1 (seconds) to taste.