# No colors for eshell?

Tags: faces, customize, eshell

I have the following in my code to customize eshell:

```
(setq eshell-prompt-function (lambda nil
    (concat
     (propertize (eshell/pwd) 'face `(:foreground "blue"))
     (propertize " $ " 'face `(:foreground "green")))))
(setq eshell-highlight-prompt nil)
```

taken from [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellPrompt#toc2).  For some reason through, my eshell goes to all white.  This code used to work for me so I must have changed something else, but I can not see why my prompt is all white. Does this have anything to do with my `~/.bashrc` or can somebody else suggest a reason why that would not color my prompt?

I am working with the GUI version on MS Windows and this all used to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eshell is an independent command interpreter implemented in Elisp, so by default it should have nothing to do with your other dotfiles, such as `~/.bashrc`.

The custom prompt function you list works for me in the development version of Emacs on GNU/Linux, so I assume the problem lies either between Emacs and Windows or with your `user-init-file`.

I am not qualified to debug or explain the former case, but the latter should be relatively straightforward to test. First [invoke Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-Startup.html) with the [`-Q` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html) and then evaluate your listed code. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Interaction.html) and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html) for ways to interactively evaluate Lisp if this is not familiar to you. Whether the custom code is evaluated before or after invoking `eshell` should not make a difference in this case (in fact, you could even compare `eshell`'s appearance before and after evaluating the code).

If the `-Q` option resolves your issue, this means it is probably arising from something in your `user-init-file`. In this case I recommend you recursively bisect it as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23772890/how-to-find-a-bug-in-emacs-or-init-el) and [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13868/how-to-get-emacs-to-locate-the-error-in-my-init-file-without-relaunching) by Drew. Otherwise I suggest emphasising that this support issue is Windows-specific.

P.S. I suggest an improvement to the custom code, to better align it with the default implementation of `eshell`:

```el
(defun my-eshell-prompt ()
  "Highlight eshell pwd and prompt separately."
  (mapconcat
   (lambda (list)
     (propertize (car list)
                 'read-only      t
                 'font-lock-face (cdr list)
                 'front-sticky   '(font-lock-face read-only)
                 'rear-nonsticky '(font-lock-face read-only)))
   `((,(abbreviate-file-name (eshell/pwd)) :foreground "blue")
     (,(if (zerop (user-uid)) " # " " $ ") :foreground "green"))
   ""))

(setq eshell-highlight-prompt nil
      eshell-prompt-function  #'my-eshell-prompt)
```

Noteworthy changes:

- Give `eshell-prompt-function` a human-readable name for `M-x describe-variable` (`C-h v`) to report.
- Make all prompt components `read-only`, so that the prompt cannot be deleted as regular text. Allow text inserted before the prompt to inherit this property, as per `eshell` defaults.
- Replace the `face` property with `font-lock-face` and do not allow text inserted after the prompt to inherit this property. I must admit I am not entirely familiar with the differences between `face` and `font-lock-face`, but I suggest this change because:

  - `eshell` does this;
  - it should achieve the same effect; and
  - the effects of `font-lock-face` can be toggled with `font-lock-mode`.
- Choose between prompts `#` and `$` depending on user privileges, as per Bourne and `eshell` defaults.
- Try to `abbreviate-file-name` of current directory as per `eshell` defaults, e.g. display `~` instead of `/path/to/user/home`.

Comment: Great improvements

Comment: If the abbreviate-file-name does not work, it may be because the path to abbreviate is not a child of your home directory. In order to make it abbreviate other paths also, add the following command before all of the above:

(setq directory-abbrev-alist (cons '("\\`c:/This/Is/My/path" . "path") directory-abbrev-alist))

Also, see this:
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Directory-Names.html