# Haskell-mode-hook help window keeps opening

Tags: hooks, haskell-mode

I installed `haskell-mode`, but every time I press <kbd>RET</kbd> or <kbd>TAB</kbd> on a Haskell file it keeps opening that window [image]

Any idea on how to deactivate this ?

Comment: This looks like an issue with your init file. You can try bisecting it to find the culprit.

Comment: I can't see any error on my init file, it keeps happening even if I change the variable.

Comment: Something in your init file must be causing it, you should be able to find the error quickly by using binary search: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13997/12563

Comment: I'm having a `Wrong type argument : stringp, nil`

Comment: As @DoMiNeLa10 suggested, please *bisect* your init file, recursively, restarting Emacs each time to narrow your init file to find the culprit. This is a binary search (1/2, 3/4, 7/8, 15/16...), so it is very quick to do.