# Cursor skips over backquotes/code blocks in markdown-mode

Tags: markdown-mode

I use [markdown-mode](https://github.com/jrblevin/markdown-mode) for editing Markdown.  When I'm trying to edit code blocks defined using backquotes (`) or multiple backquotes, my cursor skips over the backquotes, making it hard for me to edit them.  It didn't always behave this way.  How do I get the old behavior back, where there's nothing special about cursor movement around backquotes?  (Or anywhere else.)

Comment: Do you see this behavior when you run `emacs -Q`? The `-Q` flag disables your personal and site-level init files. If you don't see this new behavior then try [bisecting your init file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13868/how-to-get-emacs-to-locate-the-error-in-my-init-file-without-relaunching/13997#13997) until  you find the cause of this new behavior.

Comment: I don't see how I can do that and still have markdown-mode accessible.  (I suspect that it was a change in markdown-mode itself that's responsible, but it could be some more complicated combination of markdown-mode version with other factors.)

Comment: Start emacs with `emacs -Q your_file.md`, then do `Meta-x markdown-mode Ret` to enable `markdown-mode`.

Comment: `Meta-x markdown-mode` says, "No match," presumably because I installed the package with MELPA and it lives in `emacs.d/elpa/markdown-mode-VERSION`.  Is there a way around that?

Comment: @ceridwen you should be able to `M-x load-file` and point it to the entry file of `markdown-mode`.

Comment: It looks like an interaction between [ergoemacs-mode](https://github.com/ergoemacs/ergoemacs-mode) and markdown-mode.  Any advice on tracking down the cause?