# Evaluating the Chez Scheme code with C-x C-e

Tags: scheme

I've just installed Chez Scheme and combined it with the Geiser package using [this tutorial](https://www.travishinkelman.com/post/getting-started-with-chez-scheme-and-emacs) `M-x` `run-chez` runs quite fine but `C-x C-e` causes the Emacs Lisp rather than Chez Scheme evaluate the code.

I've read through [the Geiser cheat sheet](http://www.nongnu.org/geiser/geiser_5.html) but the key combinations listed there didn't seem to work.

What sould I do to evaluate the Chez Scheme code with `C-x C-e` ? Thanks.

Comment: What major mode is the buffer in? What is ^x^e bound to try ^hv^x^e

Comment: After I start the Chez Scheme, at the bottom of the buffer frame it writes * Chez REPL * The `C-x C-e` seems to bound to Emacs Lisp because when I enter it without any input it says `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable >)
  eval(> nil)
  elisp--eval-last-sexp(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)`

Comment: What exactly is ^x^e bound to - use help to get it there should be no seems as to what it is bound to.

Comment: I don't know how to see what ^x^e is bound to because I can't even know what ^x^e means. Is it C-x C-e?

Comment: Before Chez Scheme, I had installed Chicken Scheme too and when that mode is activated (`M-x run-scheme`) the `C-x C-e` works properly. FYI.

Comment: Yes it is C-x C-e - so what is it bound to you can tell by C-h k C-x C-e   Also note that the mode is not set ny the run command - that starts the interpreter/REPL. To see more run M-x describe-mode

Comment: `C-h k C-x C-e` gives `C-x C-e runs the command scheme-send-last-sexp (found in
inferior-scheme-mode-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp
function in ‘cmuscheme.el’.

It is bound to C-x C-e.

(scheme-send-last-sexp)

Send the previous sexp to the inferior Scheme process.`

Comment: Here are the lines from `.emacs` file related to the Chicken Scheme: `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/chicken-scheme-20141116.1939/")
(defun scheme-send-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (scheme-send-region (point-min) (point-max)))
(add-hook 'scheme-mode-hook
   '(lambda ()
      (local-set-key (kbd "M-RET") 'scheme-send-buffer)))
(add-hook 'scheme-mode-hook (lambda () (paredit-mode +1)))
(setq *scheme*  "C:/Programs/chicken-4.13.0/bin/csi -:c -w")`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to get things running in my Emacs on macOS.

- After installing chez via `brew install chezscheme`, I started my Emacs.
- In my scratch buffer I ran `(use-package geiser)` to install/initialize `geiser`.
- Then I ran `M-x customize-group` `geiser`, selected "Geiser Chez", changed the "Geiser Chez Binary" from `scheme` to `chez`, and clicked "Apply and Save"
- Created a new file `/tmp/foo.ss` via `C-x C-f`
- The modeline had Racket as the Scheme implementation, so I did `C-c C-s` `chez` to change it to Chez
- Next I did `M-x run-geiser` `chez`. The window split with the Chez chez repl on the bottom
- `C-x O` to switch out of the Chez repl back to my `foo.ss` scheme source buffer
- There I did `(+ 1 2) Ret Ret Ret` for a cheap Scheme expression and some space
- Next I did `C-x C-e` (`geiser-eval-last-sexp`) and got "=> 3" in the echo area. (It also works with `C-x C-b` (`geiser-eval-buffer`)). It looked a bit like this:

[image: screenshot of eval'ing a scheme sexp in geiser+shez]

Some things to consider:

- Make sure "Geiser Chez Binary" is point to the right binary. You can do this in a Geiser buffer with `C-h v geiser-chez-binary`.
- Make sure Chez is your active scheme implementation. This will be indicated on your modeline.
- Try this under `emacs -q` or `emacs -Q`. If it works there, but not normally the problem is in your init file(s). [Bisect your init file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13997/12713) to find the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However AFAIK the `C-x C-e` you use seem to invoke the Emacs Lisp not the Chez Scheme. You can check this out by trying a Scheme specific function like `(define (myadd arg1 arg2) (+ arg1 arg2))` If `C-x C-e` returns `symbol's function definition is void: define` than it really isn't Chez Scheme compiler being invoked.

Comment: @Romario Check what the key is bound to - here it is geiser-eval-last-sexp

Comment: @Romario `C-x C-e` is bound to `geiser-eval-last-sexp`. `C-c C-b` is bound to `geiser-eval-buffer` and eval'ing your example returns `=> #<void>`. Maybe you have something in your init file rebinding `C-x C-e`. Try all of this while running `emacs` with `-q` or `-Q`.

Comment: If I run emacs with -q/-Q all packages are off so I cannot make `M-x run-chez` or run-geiser and so I cannt test it.

Comment: Yes. That is the point. You would then use your scratch buffer (in `lisp-interaction-mode`) to manually initialize `geiser`.