# Get actual buffer name from backtrace buffer?

Tags: debugging, edebug

I have a buffer `foo.el` with some invalid code

```
(bar)
```

If i run `M-x eval-buffer`, with debug on, it show this in backtrace buffer

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function bar)
  (bar)
  eval-buffer()  ; Reading at buffer position 49
  call-interactively(eval-buffer nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-buffer)
```

I am trying to hyperlink

```
(bar)
```

to origial location which is `foo.el` at some position.

Here is what i have done so far.

```
(defun hyperlink-error-location ()
  "Hyperlink errors in backtrace."
  (interactive)
  (when (search-forward-regexp "Reading at buffer position " nil 'noerror)
    (goto-char (match-end 0))
    (let ((num (symbol-at-point)))
      (forward-line -1)
      (make-button (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)
                   'action (lambda (x) 
                             (find-file "/path/to/file")
                             (goto-char num))))))

(add-hook 'debugger-mode-hook 'hyperlink-error-location)
```

However i need original buffer name `foo.el` in backtrace buffer. How can  i get it?

Comment: You can use the variable `debugger-old-buffer`, but I am not sure your hook will work since the `mode-hook` is called before the debugger buffer is setup

Comment: Modify the backtrace function instead: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7852/show-line-number-on-error/7854#7854

Comment: Converted the comment to an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the variable `debugger-old-buffer` to get the buffer where the debugger was entered.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Iqbal Ansari comment, i have added 1 second delay to hyperlinking and its working fine.

```
(defun hyperlink-error-location ()
  "Hyperlink errors in backtrace."
  (interactive)
  (when (search-forward-regexp "Reading at buffer position " nil 'noerror)
    (goto-char (match-end 0))
    (let ((num (symbol-at-point)))
      (forward-line -1)
      (make-button (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)
                   'action (lambda (x)
                             (find-file (buffer-file-name debugger-old-buffer))
                             (goto-char num))))))

(defun debugger-timer ()
  "Timer to activate hyperlink-error-location"
  (setq debugger-timer
        (run-at-time
         (time-add (current-time) (seconds-to-time 1))
         nil 'hyperlink-error-location)))

(add-hook 'debugger-mode-hook 'debugger-timer)
```