# Why is there no line number in this debug output?

Tags: backtrace

Usually, when I get a backtrace, there is a line number.

Right now, I know where to fix this problem, but I don't understand why there is no line number I can jump to;)

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function "L")
  ("L" "Protocol Link" entry (file+headline ,(file "~/agenda/org-protocol.org") "Inbox") "* %? [[%:link][%:description]] \nCaptured On: %U")
  (add-to-list 'org-capture-templates '("P" "Protocol" entry (file+headline ,(file "~/agenda/org-protocol.org") "Inbox") "* %^{Title}\nSource: %u, %c\n #+BEGIN_QUOTE\n%i\n#+END_QUOTE\n\n\n%?") ("L" "Protocol Link" entry (file+headline ,(file "~/agenda/org-protocol.org") "Inbox") "* %? [[%:link][%:description]] \nCaptured On: %U"))
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/b0ef/.emacs.d/emacsen.el" "/home/b0ef/.emacs.d/emacsen.el" nil nil)
  load-file("/home/b0ef/.emacs.d/emacsen.el")
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/b0ef/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/b0ef/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/b0ef/.emacs.d/init" noerror nomessage)
  startup--load-user-init-file(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0xd44be122a7a0180>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x1f3c61addc0b8a75>) t)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show line number on error](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7852/show-line-number-on-error)

Comment: In `/home/b0ef/.emacs.d/emacsen.el`, you are adding to `org-capture-templates` two items (which is wrong in itself: the function can only add a single element to the list), but the second item is not quoted, so Emacs tries to evaluate it as a function call and fails.

Comment: Why you don't get a buffer position (*not* a line number), I don't know. I tried the equivalent experiment and I get `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function b)
  (b)
  (add-to-list 'foo '(a) (b))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/tmp/foo.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 70
  load-with-code-conversion("/tmp/foo.el" "/tmp/foo.el" nil t)` so I do get the buffer position. Maybe it's version dependent (although I think it's been around since 2017 or so).

Comment: How exactly are you loading the `emacsen.el` file from `init.el`? Your backtrace is missing the `eval-buffer` line which is where the `Reading at buffer position` message is attached. I don't understand why it's missing.

Comment: It would help if the OP followed up with more details, so we can figure out the problem, but in the absence of that,  the duplicate question is useful, whereas this one is not.